# Firebase Authentication as a service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building a simple app with Firebase Authentication in Angular 2.

Currently I'm able to obtain the current status of a user with details if the user is logged in with the following logic

```
  user: any;

  constructor
  (
    private af: AngularFire
  ) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user.auth.providerData[0];
      } else {
        this.user = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

However, I have to call this from multiple components and thought it would be better fit to sit in a service.
I'm struggling to find out the best way to do this.

Ideally I would

1. Create an observable in the service that monitors the status of
   auth (af.database.auth from Angular)
2. Call that function from my
   components whenever auth changes that sets the value of user in that
   specific component

Could anyone give some guidance on how best to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was loading my dataservice in another place in my app before I loaded the auth service, so this instantiated the data service too early